# Is there an extension of multinomial process models that can model several dependent variables?

Tags: multinomial-distribution, psychometrics, latent-variable, latent-class

In the setting of psychological experiments, where a categorical response has to be given, the same response can, in theory, be generated by different latent processes. For example, in an experiment where participants have to indicate whether a particular word was part of a word list they learned earlier, some correct responses may be based on actual recollection of the word, and some may be due to guessing.

Based on the proportions of yes and no responses in different conditions, multinomial process models allow one recover the occurrence probabilities of these latent processes. However, different latent processes may also effect other dependent variables. For example, they could associated with different response latencies: Guessing might require more time than a response based on recollection. **Is there an extension of multinomial process models that takes several dependent variables into account, and if so, is there software for doing that?**